# isUpdateable not behaving as expected in apex class in production

Tags: apex

We have an apex class in which an update is done on a custom object. Before the update there is a small method to check if the field of that custom object is updateable or not. 
But this code is behaving differently in production and full sandbox. We have checked the field permission for the user by querying on field permission object and it always returns true for both the environments, still in production when the class runs, it returns false. What could be the reason behind this?

```
 private static boolean canEditOnUpdate(Schema.DescribeFieldResult field, string apiName) {
    if (!field.isUpdateable()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return canEdit(field, apiName);
    }
```

Comment: FLS isn't the only concern here. Have you set/checked the permissions for the entire object after you deployed it to your production environment?

Comment: Yes, the user has full edit, read,delete permissions on that object.

Comment: Try a simple test: When logging into production as the user in question, are you able to see the field? edit it?

Comment: Oh yes, the related list is not visible in production, even though the user has full access to that object at profile level. How do we check this now?

Comment: Got it, thanks for the hint, there was a difference in the access of the master object in both the environments, hence the behavior.